# Problem while placing tiles after Re-sizing in Godot 4

Tags: godot, godot4

Hi I'm a newbie with godot so maybe my problem has a simple solution! When I load a tileset (16x16) inside godot and I use individual tiles I can position them perfectly, my problem comes once I need to group the tiles that conform a bigger figure than 16x16 and position them inside the world because they don't follow the same position grid as the other tiles formed by sets of 16x16 or individual ones. I will give more visual examples, otherwise it can be confusing.

[image]

[image]

Here you can see how the house that is formed by individual 16x16 tiles (left) is positioned differently than the one that is 1 tile only (right), what I would need would be a way that both can move freely or follow the same grid (if possible) Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. Your sprite left looks like it could also be split in 16x16 and then be saved as a pattern. Is this no option in your tilemap? Also are both houses in the same tilemap?

Comment: Yes, of course i can also compile the sprites of the house in the left but the problem is that compiled assets of multiple tiles are placed in the tilemap using a different grid from the individual tiles (they dont match the position) so for other houses in this example are not a problem but with tiles that are singular 16x16 those are imposible to place AROUND these compiled assets, and it seems that it would be an easy fix but idk